# Declare pointer to 2D enum array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, enums, multidimensional-array

Consider the MNWE:

```
enum T {VALUE};

int main() {
    T T_arr[8][8];
    T** T_arr_ptr = T_arr;
}
```

Now this does not compile, saying

> **error:** cannot convert `T(*)[8]` to `T**` in initialization

Without using `auto`, what would be the correct type for this pointer?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. `T(*T_arr_ptr)[8]` Even so, that's a pointer to a 1D array, not a pointer to a 2D array. I'm pretty sure you don't want one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D array names decays to pointer to first row of the array and hence it is of type *pointer to array*.  Here `T_arr` is of type `T(*)[8]` after decay.
Change

```
T** T_arr_ptr = T_arr;
```

to

```
T (*T_arr_ptr)[8] = T_arr;
```